# translate an image from recycler view adapter item to the image at the toolbar

Tags: java, android

//I have recycler view as follows

```
 private void prepareGridRecycleView() {
        gridRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        SpaceItemGridDecoration itemDecoration = new SpaceItemGridDecoration(10);
        gridRecyclerView.setClipToPadding(false);
        gridRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        adapter = new ShopPageGridViewAdapter(ShopPageContent.this, new ShopPageHeaderGridInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(boolean isClicked) {
                gridRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                listRecycleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, new ShopPageHeaderListInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(boolean isClicked) {

            }
        }, new CartCoordivateInfoHolder() {
            @Override
            public void setViewCoordinate(ImageView view, int x, int y) {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int pos[] = new int[2];
                cart.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
                Log.e("x", String.valueOf(pos[0]));
                Log.e("y", String.valueOf(pos[1]));
                view.bringToFront();
                Animations anim = new Animations();
                Animation a = anim.fromAtoB(20, 30, 6000,6000,null,850);
                a.setFillAfter(true);
                view.setAnimation(a);
                a.startNow();
            }
        }, new ShopPageHeaderHelpInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(boolean isClicked) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShopPageContent.this);
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.help_dialog, null);
                builder.setView(view);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            }
        }, new ShopPageHeaderFilterInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(boolean isClick) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShopPageContent.this);
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.filter_dialog, null);
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.circle_view_child);
                RangeSeekbar seekBar = (RangeSeekbar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
                seekBar.setTextMarkSize(0);
                prepareCircleImage(linearLayout);
                final TextView s = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.s);
                final TextView m = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.m);
                final TextView l = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.l);
                final TextView xl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.xl);
                final TextView xxl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.xxl);
                final TextView xxxl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.xxxl);
                s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setBackground(s);
                    }
                });
                l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setBackground(l);
                    }
                });
                m.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setBackground(m);
                    }
                });
                xl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setBackground(xl);
                    }
                });
                xxl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setBackground(xxl);
                    }
                });
                xxxl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setBackground(xxxl);
                    }
                });
                builder.setView(view);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            }
        });
        final GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return adapter.isPositionHeader(position) ? manager.getSpanCount() : 1;
            }
        });
        gridRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }
```

//the recycler view adapter seems as follows

```
public class ShopPageGridViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private ShopPageHeaderGridInterface shopPageHeaderGridInterface;
    private ShopPageHeaderListInterface shopPageHeaderListInterface;
    private ShopPageHeaderFilterInterface shopPageHeaderFilterInterface;
    private CartCoordivateInfoHolder cartCoordivateInfoHolder;
    private ShopPageHeaderHelpInterface shopPageHeaderHelpInterface;

    public ShopPageGridViewAdapter(Context context, ShopPageHeaderGridInterface shopPageHeaderGridInterface, ShopPageHeaderListInterface shopPageHeaderListInterface, CartCoordivateInfoHolder cartCoordivateInfoHolder, ShopPageHeaderHelpInterface shopPageHeaderHelpInterface, ShopPageHeaderFilterInterface shopPageHeaderFilterInterface) {
        this.context = context;
        this.shopPageHeaderGridInterface = shopPageHeaderGridInterface;
        this.shopPageHeaderListInterface = shopPageHeaderListInterface;
        this.cartCoordivateInfoHolder = cartCoordivateInfoHolder;
        this.shopPageHeaderHelpInterface = shopPageHeaderHelpInterface;
        this.shopPageHeaderFilterInterface = shopPageHeaderFilterInterface;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            list.add("hello");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shop_page_grid_layout_header, parent, false);
            final ImageView heroImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.heroImageView);
            heroImageView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    heroImageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (heroImageView.getWidth() * 0.63);
                }
            });
            final ImageView stackImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.stack_image);
            ImageView helpImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.help);
            final ImageView filterImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.filter_image);
            stackImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    shopPageHeaderGridInterface.onClick(true);
                }
            });
            final ImageView gridImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            gridImage.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    gridImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (gridImage.getHeight() * 0.80);
                    gridImage.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (gridImage.getWidth() * 0.80);
                    stackImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (stackImage.getHeight() * 0.80);
                    stackImage.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (stackImage.getWidth() * 0.80);
                    filterImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (filterImage.getHeight() * 0.80);
                    filterImage.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (filterImage.getWidth() * 0.80);
                }
            });
            gridImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    shopPageHeaderListInterface.onClick(true);
                }
            });
            helpImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    shopPageHeaderHelpInterface.onClick(true);
                }
            });
            filterImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    shopPageHeaderFilterInterface.onClick(true);
                }
            });
            return new VHHeader(v);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shop_page_grid_layout, parent, false);
            final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_parent);
            final ImageView gridItemImage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    relativeLayout.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (relativeLayout.getWidth() * 1.2);
                    relativeLayout.requestLayout();
                    gridItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.winter_sale);
                }
            });
            final ImageView cart = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cart);
            final ImageView cartNumber = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cart_number);

            cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos[] = new int[2];
                    cartNumber.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
                    Log.e("x", String.valueOf(pos[0]));
                    Log.e("y", String.valueOf(pos[1]));
                    cartCoordivateInfoHolder.setViewCoordinate(cartNumber, pos[0], pos[1]);
                }
            });
            return new VHItem(v);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
            VHHeader VHheader = (VHHeader) holder;
        } else if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
            VHItem VHitem = (VHItem) holder;

        }
    }

    //    need to override this method
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    public boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    //increasing getItemcount to 1. This will be the row of header.
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size() + 1;
    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

}
```

//So the problem I am facing is I have cart image in recycler view item and when clicked the cart image should translate to the cart icon at toolbar.But when clicked in recycler view ,item  at the cart moves around in item and not comes outside of recycler view..

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve this in many ways but i think sharedElementTransition will just do the thing for you

1. Use SharedElementTransition which make it easier as all the thing will be done by the android system itself you can reffer [SharedElementTransition](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/animations.html)

Hope it Helped :)

Comment: As per the documentation SharedElementTransition is done between two activities but in my case image is inside recycle view and cart at toolbar in same activity. So elaborate me a bit so that i can proceed with complete understanding

Comment: yes what you can do is while click on an item in recycler view navigate to other view where in the toolbar the image is displayed . using shared element transition between these  two activities will provide you the same effect which you desire